# How do we store different language words in redis as values?

Tags: redis

I want to store the data received from API and store it as a value in Redis.The response would be in different languages
eg:
I want to store the response ದಿನಾಂಕ .But whenever i try to access the value throug key the response would be something like "\xe0\xb2\xa6\xe0\xb2\xbf\xe0\xb2\xa8\xe0\xb2\xbe\xe0\xb2\x82\xe0\xb2\x95" .
Please help if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply the array of bytes (hexadecimal representation) of your string (UTF-8 representation).

For example, input `e0 b2 a6 e0 b2 bf e0 b2 a8 e0 b2 be e0 b2 82 e0 b2 95` in https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-bytes-to-utf8.

All you should do is use a function (depending on your programming language or Redis client) to convert an array of bytes into its UTF-8 string representation.

See [Python-redis keys() returns list of bytes objects instead of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026515/python-redis-keys-returns-list-of-bytes-objects-instead-of-strings).