# Redis HGETALL returns each key-value as byte objects individually

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I am using Python as client to interact with redis and using the following Python library to do so:
https://github.com/redis/redis-py

When I run the command:

```
redis_return = conn.hgetall('my-hash-key')
```

What I get in return is a dictionary with all its elements as bytes objects individually, like:

```
{b'key1': b'value1', b'key2': b'value2'}
```

Since I need them as string I am looping over the dictionary and on each iteration decoding they key and value, something like:

```
mydict = dict()
for keys in redis_return:
    mydict[keys.decode('utf-8')] = redis_return[keys].decode('utf-8')
```

I am getting the results in mydict as I need it, but is this the right approach?
Seems tedious and I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026515/python-redis-keys-returns-list-of-bytes-objects-instead-of-strings) you need to pass `decode_responses=True` when you create your connection.

Comment: This seems to be a life saver. My code is full of response.decode('utf-8') splattered all over the place!