# Python redis pubsub: what happen to types when it gets published?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

pub.py

```
import redis
import datetime
import time

def main():
    redis_host = '10.235.13.29'
        r = redis.client.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=6379)
        while True:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print 'Sending {0}'.format(now)
            print 'data type is %s' % type(now)
            r.publish('clock', now)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Sending 2014-10-08 13:10:58.338765
data type is <type 'datetime.datetime'>
Sending 2014-10-08 13:10:59.368707
data type is <type 'datetime.datetime'>
Sending 2014-10-08 13:11:00.378723
data type is <type 'datetime.datetime'>
Sending 2014-10-08 13:11:01.398132
data type is <type 'datetime.datetime'>
Sending 2014-10-08 13:11:02.419030
data type is <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

sub.py

```
import redis
import threading
import time
import datetime

def callback():
    redis_host = '10.235.13.29'
    r = redis.client.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=6379)
    sub = r.pubsub()
    sub.subscribe('clock')
    while True:
        for m in sub.listen():
            #print m #'Recieved: {0}'.format(m['data'])
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print 'Recieved: %s at %s' % (m['data'], now)
            print 'Data type is %s' % type(m['data'])
            dur = 1
            print 'It took %s to receive' % dur

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    while True:
        print 'Waiting'
        time.sleep(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
{}: ./sub.py
Waiting
Recieved: 1 at 2014-10-08 13:09:36.708088
Data type is <type 'long'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:37.629664 at 2014-10-08 13:09:37.630479
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:38.630661 at 2014-10-08 13:09:38.631585
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:39.632663 at 2014-10-08 13:09:39.633480
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:40.633662 at 2014-10-08 13:09:40.634464
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:41.634665 at 2014-10-08 13:09:41.635557
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:42.635662 at 2014-10-08 13:09:42.636673
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:43.642665 at 2014-10-08 13:09:43.643441
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:44.643663 at 2014-10-08 13:09:44.644582
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:45.644667 at 2014-10-08 13:09:45.673734
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:46.672918 at 2014-10-08 13:09:46.673874
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:47.673913 at 2014-10-08 13:09:47.675014
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:48.674920 at 2014-10-08 13:09:48.675804
Data type is <type 'str'>
It took 1 to receive
Recieved: 2014-10-08 13:09:49.675912 at 2014-10-08 13:09:49.677346
Data type is <type 'str'>
```

The type changed from datetime.datetime to str
Is it possible to preserve the type because i am trying to find the duration i cant subtracte datetime obj to str?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/

I think you must serialize the datetime object in published channel, then deserialize when reading the sub.

I noticed you commented on the solution already :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400288/152016

---

EDIT:

You could store epoch seconds in the key and avoid serializing! (if you only will publish datetimes).