# Unpickling "None" object in Python

Tags: python, redis, pickle

I am using `redis` to try to save a request's session object.  Based on [how to store a complex object in redis (using redis-py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py), I have:

```
def get_object_redis(key,r):
    saved = r.get(key)
    obj = pickle.loads(saved)
    return obj

redis = Redis()
s = get_object_redis('saved',redis)
```

I have situations where there is no saved session and 'saved' evaluates to `None`. In this case I get:

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

Whats the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with it. This is what they would have in common:

```
def get_object_redis(key,r):
    saved = r.get(key)
    if saved is None:
        # maybe add code here
        return ... # return something you expect
    obj = pickle.loads(saved)
    return obj
```

You need to make it clear what you expect if a key is not found.

**Version 1**
An example would be you just return None:

```
def get_object_redis(key,r):
    saved = r.get(key)
    if saved is None:
        return None
    obj = pickle.loads(saved)
    return obj

redis = Redis()
s = get_object_redis('saved',redis)
```

`s` is then `None`. This may be bad because you need to handle that somewhere and you do not know whether it was not found or it was found and really `None`.

**Version 2**
You create an object, maybe based on the key, that you can construct because you know what lies behind a key.

```
class KeyWasNotFound(object):
    # just an example class
    # maybe you have something useful in mind
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

def get_object_redis(key,r):
    saved = r.get(key)
    if saved is None:
        return KeyWasNotFound(key)
    obj = pickle.loads(saved)
    return obj
```

Usually, if identity is important, you would store the object after you created it, to return the same object for the key.

**Version 3**
TypeError is a very geneneric error. You can create your own error class. This would be the preferred way for me, because I do not like version 1 and do not have knowledge of which object would be useful to return.

```
class NoRedisObjectFoundForKey(KeyError):
    pass

def get_object_redis(key,r):
    saved = r.get(key)
    if saved is None:
        raise NoRedisObjectFoundForKey(key)
    obj = pickle.loads(saved)
    return obj
```

Comment: Consider to post the addendum as a new question. Otherwise much fewer people will read it. It is a totally different question. @user61629

Comment: a follow up question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254837/python-pickle-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range