# How to make a class with an inner class JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, inner-classes

I would like to automatically convert a Python class into a dictionary so I can convert it to JSON. The question [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) suggests to use `myClass.__dict__`, however, using this does not turn any inner classes into a JSON serializable object.

The following example...

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = [self.Thing2(self)]

    class Thing2():
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.name = parent.name + "'s child"

myThing = Thing("Clay")
print(myThing.__dict__)
```

yields the result...

```
{'name': 'Clay', 'children': [<__main__.Thing.Thing2 object at 0x00000257C4358B00>]}
```

which is still not JSON serializable. How do I convert a class AND INNER CLASSES into a JSON serializable object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `myClass.__dict__` does not work on inner classes, you can define your own method to convert your class into a dictionary, as long as you know what fields are an Object.

The follow example...

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = [self.Thing2(self)]

    def to_dict(self):
        dict = self.__dict__
        dict["children"] = [child.__dict__ for child in dict["children"]]
        return dict


    class Thing2():
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.name = parent.name + "'s child"


my_thing = Thing("Clay")
print(my_thing.__dict__)
print(my_thing.to_dict())
```

yields the result...

```
{'name': 'Clay', 'children': [<__main__.Thing.Thing2 object at 0x00000257C4358B00>]}
{'name': 'Clay', 'children': [{'name': "Clay's child"}]}
```

which can be converted into JSON using `json.dumps()`.

If you do not know what fields in your class are JSON serializable and which are inner classes, you could iterate over the values in your class's dictionary, [check if they are JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033142/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-json-serializable-in-python), and convert them to dictionaries (`value.__dict__`) as necessary.