# Storing a custom Python object in Redis

Tags: python, redis

I'm trying to store a custom, serializable python object in Redis, but have encountered some strange behavior. The `set` method seems to function, but the `get` method only returns the value of the object's `__repr__` method. For instance...

```
import redis

# initialize the redis connection pool
rs = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

# define a custom class
class SomeCustomObject(object):
    pass
```

When I try to set the `SomeCustomObject` as a value, it appears to work:

```
>>> rs.set('c', SomeCustomObject())
True
```

However, when I `get` the value back, it's just the `__repr__` string:

```
>>> rs.get('c')
'<__main__.SomeCustomObject object at 0x102496710>'
```

How do I store/get the instance back? I've not had much luck finding any info on this in [the documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but surely I'm not the first one to encounter this?

Comment: Where are you serializing the object?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Use Pickle**

Using the pickle module you can serialize and deserialize Python objects and pass them to Redis.

From this so answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400288/4403600, it would look like this:

```
import pickle
import redis

# define a custom class
class SomeCustomObject(object):
    pass

# initialize the redis connection pool
rs = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

# pickle and set in redis
rs.set('c', pickle.dumps(SomeCustomObject()))

# get from redis and unpickle
unpacked_object = pickle.loads(rs.get('c'))
```

Further reading - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Ah, this is great. I was (for whatever misguided reason) under the impression redis-py would handle the pickling, so long as I had the `__getstate__`, `__setstate__` pieces handled. Thank you!