# How to save complicated data structure in Redis?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, redis

I'm new to python. I'm getting errors when running my code:

```
import redis

def redisSave(case, key, ob):
    dataBase = None
    if case == 'Product':
        dataBase = redis.Redis(db=0)
        dataBase.set(key, ob)
        dataBase.expire(key, time=600)
    else:
        pass

dictOb = {
    'price': '2000 $',
    'weight': '50 lb'
}
redisSave('Product', 'first', dictOb)
```

It says that input type is invalid (redis.exceptions.DataError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
def redis_save(case, key, obj):
    data_base = None

    if case == 'Product':
        data_base = redis.Redis(db=0)

        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            data_base.hmset(key, obj)
            data_base.expire(key, time=600)
```

**Access the data:** `data_base.hgetall('first')`

**Result:**

```
{
    b'price': b'2000 $',
    b'weight': b'50 lb'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the data as a **JSON-dump** or as a **pickled object**. See: [how to store a complex object in redis (using redis-py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py).

Comment: Please read the discussions in the comments in that thread as well, for a well informed decision on which option is best for you.