# Is it safe to convert JSON into string for redis key-value storage?

Tags: javascript, redis

So I read somewhere that storing object into Redis using pickle (Python) could result in [malicious code running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20400288/9964717) (It being binary data)
In context to this, I want to store an array of object created by **end-user** as cache in Redis. The best solution that I have come up with is to stringify the object and create an array of strings.

My concern is since the object will be created by the end-user is it safe to use the aforementioned method of converting JSON to BSON or work with stringify with Redis (I am using javascript)?

Data Eg:

```
[{"fname": "temp.txt", "size": 50, "type":"pdf", "mt": "Timestamp"},{..},...]
```

PS: I will be using javascript and not python. Also, any alternate solution which is faster/safer is welcomed.

Comment: JSON is a text format.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have update the question... My concern is - is it better (as in faster/safer) to convert JSON to BSON or work with stringify.