# Retrieve a stored file in redis using python

Tags: python, redis

I get a file in requests and I'm storing it in redis . When I retrieve it I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

```
Files = request.getlist('files')
For file in files:
    redis_client.set('filename',file.read())
```

When I try to retrieve it with

```
redis_client.get('filename')
```

I get the error, although when I get it using redis cli it returns
bytes but when i try it in python it gives above error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to store a complex object in redis (using redis-py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219858/how-to-store-a-complex-object-in-redis-using-redis-py)