# Save dict to pickle or write to file?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a Python script that returns a dict which I want to store somewhere to be used in a bigger project (the script is slow to run so I don't want to just import the script each time I want the dictionary).

The dict is small so I see two options. I can:

1. Save the dict to a pickle file
2. Write the dict as a literal to a new .py file, like so:

   ```
   my_dict = slow_func()
   with open('stored_dict.py', 'w') as py_file:
       file_contents = 'stored_dict = ' + str(my_dict)
       py_file.write(my_dict)
   ```

   Then I can access the dict literal using `from stored_dict import stored_dict`

Should I prefer one of these options?

Comment: You can dump it to `JSON` file, which looks as same as dict.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json

Comment: Depends a bit on the data contained in that dictionary...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python dict is implemented like `json`. You can use the `json` module to dump a dict into file, and load it back easily:

```
import json

d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

with open('C:\temp.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(d, file)

with open('C:\temp.txt', 'r') as file:
    new_d = json.load(file)

>>> new_d
{u'1': u'a', u'3': u'c', u'2': u'b'}
```

Comment: I have dataframes inside my dictionary and I get the error: `TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 5):

In my personal experience, I suggest using JSON if:

- You want a human-readable file,
- A file type that is compatible across multiple technologies without very much implementation overhead.
- An easily editable file (as it can simply be a text file).

I would suggest using Pickle if:

- The majority of the project will be written in python.
- The dictionary is likely to become very large/complex or rolled into a larger class.
- A non-human readable file is required.
- A file that is difficult to edit without prior knowledge of its construction.

Based on the situation you touch upon in your question, JSON would be the more beneficial choice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Chad. I was planning to do pickle, but I know it would be valuable to still have the dictionary readable in plaintext; therefore I am opting to use Json.