# Pickle Dump Code Problem: content in .txt file

Tags: python, encoding, pickle

Here's my code:

```
list = ["example"]
def speichern(charts):
    f = open("test.txt", "wb")
    pickle.dump(list, f, )
    f.close()
```

It works, but the content of `test.txt` is:

```
€]q ]q(X   exampleqX    qea
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's nothing to "fix" here. What did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, but you're writing binary pickle content to that file. You need to unpickle it when you load it again. If you want it to be human readable, you want to json.dump() it, not pickle it.

Comment: not sure where is the problem , please read about `pickle.dump` and you will see it is expected behavior . see : https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: ty guys :D someone can say me whats 
advantage and disadvantage for using pickle dump or json dump?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json