# How to display html file with Dash HTML components

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I plotted a figure that I saved in *fig.html* and I would like to display it with dash-html-components.

Which Dash HTML component should I use and what is the exact syntax? I have tried several components from the dash list but I think I am not using it the right way.

this is my current result:

[image]

Here is an example of what I tried:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['../app/css/template.css'])

app.title = 'Test Dashboard'

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(
      children='Test Dashboard',
      style={
         'textAlign': 'center'
      }
    ),

    html.Br(),

    html.Iframe(src='fig.html')

],
style={'width': '75%',
          'textAlign': 'center',
          'margin-left':'12.5%',
          'margin-right':'0'
         }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since figures in Dash are essentially dictionaries, which are serialized to JSON and passed to plotly.js for rendering (for details, see the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#representing-figures)), i would consider JSON as the preferred format for saving the figure. Here is a small example app (requires Dash 0.0.12),

```
import json
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

cache = "fig.json"
# Construct a figure object and save it as json.
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
with open(cache, 'w') as f:
    f.write(fig.to_json())
# Create example app.
app = dash.Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="graph"), html.Button("Click me", id="btn")])


@app.callback(Output("graph", "figure"), [Input("btn", "n_clicks")])
def func(n_clicks):
    with open(cache, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Compared to pickle, JSON also has the advantage of being human readable, and you avoid the `pickle.load` statement, which can potentially introduce security vulnerabilities. For an extended discussion of pickle vs JSON, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json).

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I finaly saved my graph with pickle:

```
import pickle

filename = 'graph.pkl'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(fig, f)
```

and then load it where I need it:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pickle

filename = 'graph.pkl'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    fig = pickle.load(f)

html.Div([dcc.Graph(figure=fig)])
```

But I am still interested to know if this is a good way to do it or not.