# Parse JSON into a dictionary of objects

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My JSON reads:

```json
{
    "employee_1": {"name": "Sarah"},
    "employee_2": {"name": "Emma"}
}
```

Which is created as:

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


employees = {}
employees["employee_1"] = Employee("Sarah")
employees["employee_2"] = Employee("Emma")
json_str = json.dumps(employees, 
                      default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
```

I write this JSON to a file and later on, load it from the file. However, the loaded object is deserialized as a dictionary of dictionaries, rather than a dictionary of `Employee`s.

```py
loaded_employees = json.loads(json_str)

print(type(employees["employee_1"]))
print(type(loaded_employees["employee_1"]))
```

Output is:

```
<class '__main__.Employee'>
<class 'dict'>
```

I want the loaded `employee_1` to be of type `Employee`, exactly as it was when persisting to JSON.

I think this should be achievable leveraging `object_hook`; [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882054/947889) or  [`object_hook` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) explain how to use it for "flat" type object (for the lack of a better word), though not sure how I can use it for a dictionary of custom type as is here.

Comment: JSON can't store class information.

Comment: Use a lib like marshmallow

Comment: JSON is text based and so they cant store classes which have things like methods. Its like this because sometimes you want to use this data from other files which might not have this class and so they cant just make a way to dump it into a string. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation which doesnt have anything but text so it wouldnt make sense to be able to have a class. What I do is just remake teh class

Comment: If you know that the JSON contains `Employee` objects, you can loop over the dictionary and convert them to `Employee`.

Comment: I know in C# you can simply convert this JSON back to object if you specify your JSON is of type `Dictionary<string, Employee>`; like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Employee>>(json)`

Comment: Python's object serialization feature is called [pickling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/object_oriented_python/object_oriented_python_serialization.htm), but it's not JSON. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259270/pickle-or-json

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, interoperability and human-readability is a requirement of my (de)serialization; hence I am guessing pickling would not help much.

Comment: There are folks who have built serialization formats that allow type data to be represented (yaml can do this; so can EDN). There wouldn't be any _need_ for that if JSON could do it. (Okay, EDN adds other niceties too, but tagged content is certainly one of them).

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you want to do is make your init statement take in  a dictionary like it does now and then create the classes by looping over your dictionary or list from json. You will also have to make a specific dump function that will dump all the variables in the object into a dictionary to move into json.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dictionary elements to `Employee` after loading the JSON.

```
employees = json.loads(json_str)
for k, v in employees.items():
    employees[k] = Employee(**v)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My only concern about this approach is it will lead to a wordy and less-portable solution in a real-world application. For instance, if `Employee` has a member that is a dictionary of another type (e.g., `Managers`), then I would need to repeat the same process for that member. And all of that implementation would need to be updated anytime the `Employee` type is modified.

Comment: That's true, there's no really general solution with JSON.