# How is it that json serialization is so much faster than yaml serialization in Python?

Tags: python, json, serialization, yaml

I have code that relies heavily on yaml for cross-language serialization and while working on speeding some stuff up I noticed that yaml was insanely slow compared to other serialization methods (e.g., pickle, json).

So what really blows my mind is that json is so much faster that yaml when the output is nearly identical.

```
>>> import yaml, cjson; d={'foo': {'bar': 1}}
>>> yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
'foo: {bar: 1}\n'
>>> cjson.encode(d)
'{"foo": {"bar": 1}}'
>>> import yaml, cjson;
>>> timeit("yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)", setup="import yaml; d={'foo': {'bar': 1}}", number=10000)
44.506911039352417
>>> timeit("yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.CSafeDumper)", setup="import yaml; d={'foo': {'bar': 1}}", number=10000)
16.852826118469238
>>> timeit("cjson.encode(d)", setup="import cjson; d={'foo': {'bar': 1}}", number=10000)
0.073784112930297852
```

PyYaml's CSafeDumper and cjson are both written in C so it's not like this is a C vs Python speed issue. I've even added some random data to it to see if cjson is doing any caching, but it's still way faster than PyYaml. I realize that yaml is a superset of json, but how could the yaml serializer be 2 orders of magnitude slower with such simple input?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In general, it's not the complexity of the output that determines the speed of parsing, but the complexity of the accepted input. The JSON grammar is [very concise](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). The YAML parsers are [comparatively complex](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2763452), leading to increased overheads.

> JSON’s foremost design goal is
>   simplicity and universality. Thus,
>   JSON is trivial to generate and parse,
>   at the cost of reduced human
>   readability. It also uses a lowest
>   common denominator information model,
>   ensuring any JSON data can be easily
>   processed by every modern programming
>   environment.
>
> In contrast, YAML’s foremost design
>   goals are human readability and
>   support for serializing arbitrary
>   native data structures. Thus, YAML
>   allows for extremely readable files,
>   but is more complex to generate and
>   parse. In addition, YAML ventures
>   beyond the lowest common denominator
>   data types, requiring more complex
>   processing when crossing between
>   different programming environments.

I'm not a YAML parser implementor, so I can't speak specifically to the orders of magnitude without some profiling data and a big corpus of examples. In any case, be sure to test over a large body of inputs before feeling confident in benchmark numbers.

**Update** Whoops, misread the question. :-( Serialization can still be blazingly fast despite the large input grammar; however, browsing the source, it looks like PyYAML's Python-level serialization [constructs a representation graph](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dumper) whereas simplejson encodes builtin Python datatypes directly into text chunks.

Comment: (Just an example of how concise the JSON grammar is, you can't have an extraneous trailing comma at the end of an array. Overkill IMO.)

Comment: He's asking about encoding, not parsing.

Comment: YAML builds a graph because it is a general-purpose serialisation format that is able to represent multiple references to the same object. If you know no object is repeated and only basic types appear, you can use a json serialiser, it will still be valid YAML.

Comment: @Tobu Useful comment - I took the liberty to quote it in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743711/can-i-speedup-yaml/27744056#27744056)

Comment: @cdleary You should point to the source of PyYAML and not to the documentation. The wording of the documentation is incorrect, there is no graph-building code, nor any graph like data-structure. The representer builds a linear stream and there is no cross connection between the elements of the stream, only some bucket of IDs to prevent infinite recursion (and thereby support anchors/aliases). No part of a `Node` points to another `Node`.

Comment: @Tobu PyYAML doesn't build a graph. You only need to keep track of the IDs of previously traversed objects to deal with multiple references and that is what PyYAML does. See my comment to cdleary.

Answer (score 39):

In applications I've worked on, the type inference between strings to numbers (float/int) is where the largest overhead is for parsing yaml is because strings can be written without quotes.  Because all strings in json are in quotes there is no backtracking when parsing strings.  A great example where this would slow down is the value 0000000000000000000s.  You cannot tell this value is a string until you've read to the end of it.

The other answers are correct but this is a specific detail that I've discovered in practice.

Answer (score 26):

Speaking about efficiency, I used YAML for a time and felt attracted by the simplicity that some name/value assignments take on in this language. However, in the process I tripped so and so often about one of YAML’s finesses, subtle variations in the grammar that allow you to write special cases in a more concise style and such. In the end, although YAML’s grammar is almost for certain formally consistent, it has left me with a certain feeling of ‘vagueness’. I then restricted myself to not touch existing, working YAML code and write everything new in a more roundabout, fail-safe syntax—which made me abandon all of YAML. The upshot is that YAML tries to look like a W3C standard, and produces a small library of hard to read literature concerning its concepts and rules.

This, I feel, is by far more intellectual overhead than needed. Look at SGML/XML: developed by IBM in the roaring 60s, standardized by the ISO, known (in a dumbed-down and modified form) as HTML to uncounted millions of people, documented and documented and documented again the world over. Comes up little JSON and slays that dragon. How could JSON become so widely used in so short a time, with just one meager website (and a javascript luminary to back it)? It is in its simplicity, the sheer absence of doubt in its grammar, the ease of learning and using it.

XML and YAML are hard for humans, and they are hard for computers. JSON is quite friendly and easy to both humans and computers.

Comment: JSON can be natively parsed by web browsers which sets it apart from any other representation format and might explain its wide adoption.

Answer (score 13):

A cursory look at python-yaml suggests its design is much more complex than cjson's:

```
>>> dir(cjson)
['DecodeError', 'EncodeError', 'Error', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__version__', 'decode', 'encode']

>>> dir(yaml)
['AliasEvent', 'AliasToken', 'AnchorToken', 'BaseDumper', 'BaseLoader', 'BlockEndToken',
 'BlockEntryToken', 'BlockMappingStartToken', 'BlockSequenceStartToken', 'CBaseDumper',
'CBaseLoader', 'CDumper', 'CLoader', 'CSafeDumper', 'CSafeLoader', 'CollectionEndEvent', 
'CollectionNode', 'CollectionStartEvent', 'DirectiveToken', 'DocumentEndEvent', 'DocumentEndToken', 
'DocumentStartEvent', 'DocumentStartToken', 'Dumper', 'Event', 'FlowEntryToken', 
'FlowMappingEndToken', 'FlowMappingStartToken', 'FlowSequenceEndToken', 'FlowSequenceStartToken', 
'KeyToken', 'Loader', 'MappingEndEvent', 'MappingNode', 'MappingStartEvent', 'Mark', 
'MarkedYAMLError', 'Node', 'NodeEvent', 'SafeDumper', 'SafeLoader', 'ScalarEvent', 
'ScalarNode', 'ScalarToken', 'SequenceEndEvent', 'SequenceNode', 'SequenceStartEvent', 
'StreamEndEvent', 'StreamEndToken', 'StreamStartEvent', 'StreamStartToken', 'TagToken', 
'Token', 'ValueToken', 'YAMLError', 'YAMLObject', 'YAMLObjectMetaclass', '__builtins__', 
'__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '__with_libyaml__', 
'add_constructor', 'add_implicit_resolver', 'add_multi_constructor', 'add_multi_representer', 
'add_path_resolver', 'add_representer', 'compose', 'compose_all', 'composer', 'constructor', 
'cyaml', 'dump', 'dump_all', 'dumper', 'emit', 'emitter', 'error', 'events', 'load', 
'load_all', 'loader', 'nodes', 'parse', 'parser', 'reader', 'representer', 'resolver', 
'safe_dump', 'safe_dump_all', 'safe_load', 'safe_load_all', 'scan', 'scanner', 'serialize', 
'serialize_all', 'serializer', 'tokens']
```

More complex designs almost invariably mean slower designs, and this is far more complex than most people will ever need.

Comment: To be fair, you are only commenting on how much of the complexity is exposed in the top-level public API. (It is only coincidental that YAML actually is more complex than JSON, and therefore most data that can be expressed in JSON will be more efficient to express as JSON.) But there is nothing preventing a python library for yaml from presenting a simpler API, or a json API from exposing more internal details.

Answer (score 12):

Although you have an accepted answer, unfortunately that only does
some handwaving in the direction of the PyYAML documentation and
quotes a statement in that documentation that is not correct: PyYAML
does **not** make a representation graph during dumping, it creates a
lineair stream (and just like `json` keeps a bucket of IDs to see if there are
recursions).

---

First of all you have to realize that while the `cjson` dumper is
handcrafted C-code only, YAML's CSafeDumper shares two of the four dump stages
(`Representer` and `Resolver`) with the normal pure Python SafeDumper
and that the other two stages (the Serializer and Emitter) are not
written completely handcrafted in C, but consist of  a Cython module 
which calls the C library `libyaml` for emitting.

---

Apart from that significant part, the simple answer to your question
why it takes longer, is that dumping YAML does more. This is not so
much because YAML is harder as @flow claims, but because that extra
that YAML can do, makes it so much more powerful than JSON and also more
user friendly, if you need to process the result with an editor. That
means more time is spent in the YAML library even when applying these extra features, 
and in many cases also just checking if something applies.

Here is an example: even if you have never gone through the PyYAML
code, you'll have noticed that the dumper doesn't quote `foo` and
`bar`. That is not because these strings are are keys, as YAML doesn't
have the restriction that JSON has, that a key for a mapping needs to
be string. E.g. a Python string that is a value in mapping **can**
also be unquoted (i.e. plain).

The emphasis is on **can**, because it is not always so. Take for
instance a string that consists of numeral characters only:
`12345678`. This needs to be written out with quotes as otherwise this
would look exactly like a number (and read back in as such when parsing).

How does PyYAML know when to quote a string and when not? On dumping
it actually first dumps the string, then parses the result to make
sure, that when it reads that result back, it gets the original value.
And if that proves not to be the case, it applies quotes.

Let me repeat the important part of the previous sentence again, so
you don't have to re-read it:

> it dumps the string, then parses the result

This means it applies all of the regex matching it does when
loading to see if the resulting scalar would load as an integer,
float, boolean, datetime, etc., to determine whether quotes need to be
applied or not.¹

---

In any real application with complex data, a JSON based
dumper/loader is too simple to use directly and a lot more
intelligence has to be in your program compared to dumping the same
complex data directly to YAML. A simplified example is when you want to work
with date-time stamps, in that case you have to convert a string back
and forth to `datetime.datetime` yourself if you are using JSON. During loading
you have to do that either based on the fact that this is a value
associated with some (hopefully recognisable) key:

```
{ "datetime": "2018-09-03 12:34:56" }
```

or with a position in a list:

```
["FirstName", "Lastname", "1991-09-12 08:45:00"]
```

or based on the format of the string (e.g. using regex).

In all of these cases much more work needs to be done in your program. The same
holds for dumping and that does not only mean extra development time.

Lets regenerate your timings with what I get on my machine
so we can compare them with other measurements. I rewrote your code
somewhat, because it was incomplete (`timeit`?) and imported other
things twice.  It was also impossible to just cut and paste because of the `>>>` prompts.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import yaml
import cjson
from timeit import timeit

NR=10000
ds = "; d={'foo': {'bar': 1}}"
d = {'foo': {'bar': 1}}

print('yaml.SafeDumper:', end=' ')
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
print('cjson.encode:   ', cjson.encode(d))
print()


res = timeit("yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)", setup="import yaml"+ds, number=NR)
print('yaml.SafeDumper ', res)
res = timeit("yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.CSafeDumper)", setup="import yaml"+ds, number=NR)
print('yaml.CSafeDumper', res)
res = timeit("cjson.encode(d)", setup="import cjson"+ds, number=NR)
print('cjson.encode    ', res)
```

and this outputs:

```
yaml.SafeDumper: foo: {bar: 1}
cjson.encode:    {"foo": {"bar": 1}}

yaml.SafeDumper  3.06794905663
yaml.CSafeDumper 0.781533956528
cjson.encode     0.0133550167084
```

Now lets 
dump a simple data structure that includes a `datetime`

```
import datetime
from collections import Mapping, Sequence  # python 2.7 has no .abc

d = {'foo': {'bar': datetime.datetime(1991, 9, 12, 8, 45, 0)}}

def stringify(x, key=None):
    # key parameter can be used to dump
    if isinstance(x, str):
       return x
    if isinstance(x, Mapping):
       res = {}
       for k, v in x.items():
           res[stringify(k, key=True)] = stringify(v)  # 
       return res
    if isinstance(x, Sequence):
        res = [stringify(k) for k in x]
        if key:
            res = repr(res)
        return res
    if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
        return x.isoformat(sep=' ')
    return repr(x)

print('yaml.CSafeDumper:', end=' ')
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.CSafeDumper)
print('cjson.encode:    ', cjson.encode(stringify(d)))
print()
```

This gives:

```
yaml.CSafeDumper: foo: {bar: '1991-09-12 08:45:00'}
cjson.encode:     {"foo": {"bar": "1991-09-12 08:45:00"}}
```

For the timing of the above I created a module myjson that wraps
`cjson.encode` and has the above `stringify` defined. If you use that:

```
d = {'foo': {'bar': datetime.datetime(1991, 9, 12, 8, 45, 0)}}
ds = 'import datetime, myjson, yaml; d=' + repr(d)
res = timeit("yaml.dump(d, Dumper=yaml.CSafeDumper)", setup=ds, number=NR)
print('yaml.CSafeDumper', res)
res = timeit("myjson.encode(d)", setup=ds, number=NR)
print('cjson.encode    ', res)
```

giving:

```
yaml.CSafeDumper 0.813436031342
cjson.encode     0.151570081711
```

That still rather simple output, already brings you back from two orders
of magnitude difference in speed to less than only one order of magnitude.

---

YAML's plain scalars and block style formatting make for better readable data.
That you can have a trailing comma in a sequence (or mapping) makes for
less failures when manually editing YAML data as with same data in JSON.

YAML tags allow for in-data indication of your (complex) types. When
using JSON *you* have to take care, in your code, of anything more
complex than mappings, sequences, integers, floats, booleans and
strings.  Such code requires development time, and is unlikely to be
as fast as `python-cjson` (you are of course free to write your code
in C as well.

Dumping some data, like recursive data-structures (e.g. topological
data), or complex keys is pre-defined in the PyYAML library. There the
JSON library just errors out, and implement workaround for that is
non-trivial and most likely slows things that speed differences are less relevant.

Such power and flexibility comes at a price of lower speed.  When
dumping many simple things JSON is the better choice, you are unlikely
going to edit the result by hand anyway. For anyting that involves
editing or complex objects or both, you should still consider using
YAML.

---

¹ <sub>It is possible to force dumping of all Python strings as YAML
scalars with (double) quotes, but setting the style is not enough to
prevent all readback.</sub>