# Can I speedup YAML?

Tags: python, json, yaml

I made a little test case to compare YAML and JSON speed :

```
import json
import yaml
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

NB_ROW=1024

print 'Does yaml is using libyaml ? ',yaml.__with_libyaml__ and 'yes' or 'no'

dummy_data = [ { 'dummy_key_A_%s' % i: i, 'dummy_key_B_%s' % i: i } for i in xrange(NB_ROW) ]


with open('perf_json_yaml.yaml','w') as fh:
    t1 = datetime.now()
    yaml.safe_dump(dummy_data, fh, encoding='utf-8', default_flow_style=False)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    dty = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()
    print 'Dumping %s row into a yaml file : %s' % (NB_ROW,dty)

with open('perf_json_yaml.json','w') as fh:
    t1 = datetime.now()
    json.dump(dummy_data,fh)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    dtj = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()
    print 'Dumping %s row into a json file : %s' % (NB_ROW,dtj)

print "json is %dx faster for dumping" % (dty/dtj)

with open('perf_json_yaml.yaml') as fh:
    t1 = datetime.now()
    data = yaml.safe_load(fh)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    dty = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()
    print 'Loading %s row from a yaml file : %s' % (NB_ROW,dty)

with open('perf_json_yaml.json') as fh:
    t1 = datetime.now()
    data = json.load(fh)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    dtj = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()
    print 'Loading %s row into from json file : %s' % (NB_ROW,dtj)

print "json is %dx faster for loading" % (dty/dtj)
```

And the result is :

```
Does yaml is using libyaml ?  yes
Dumping 1024 row into a yaml file : 0.251139
Dumping 1024 row into a json file : 0.007725
json is 32x faster for dumping
Loading 1024 row from a yaml file : 0.401224
Loading 1024 row into from json file : 0.001793
json is 223x faster for loading
```

I am using PyYAML 3.11 with libyaml C library on ubuntu 12.04.
I know that json is much more simple than yaml, but with a 223x ratio between json and yaml I am wondering whether my configuration is correct or not.

Do you have same speed ratio ?
How can I speed up `yaml.load()` ?

Answer (score 46):

You've probably noticed that Python's syntax for data structures is **very** similar to JSON's syntax.

What's happening is Python's `json` library encodes Python's builtin datatypes [directly into text chunks](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/json/decoder.py), replacing `'` into `"` and deleting `,` here and there (to oversimplify a bit).

On the other hand, `pyyaml` has to [construct a whole representation graph](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dumper) before serialising it into a string.

The same kind of stuff has to happen backwards when loading.

The only way to speedup `yaml.load()` would be to write a new `Loader`, but I doubt it could be a huge leap in performance, except if you're willing to write your own single-purpose sort-of `YAML` parser, taking [the following comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451732/how-is-it-that-json-serialization-is-so-much-faster-than-yaml-serialization-in-p#comment7661771_2452043) in consideration:

> YAML builds a graph because it is a general-purpose serialisation
> format that is able to represent multiple references to the same
> object. If you know no object is repeated and only basic types appear,
> you can use a json serialiser, it will still be valid YAML.

-- **UPDATE**

What I said before remains true, but if you're running `Linux` there's a way to speed up `Yaml` parsing. By default, Python's `yaml` uses the Python parser. You have to tell it that you want to use `PyYaml` `C` parser.

You can do it this way:

```
import yaml
from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper

dump = yaml.dump(dummy_data, fh, encoding='utf-8', default_flow_style=False, Dumper=Dumper)
data = yaml.load(fh, Loader=Loader)
```

In order to do so, you need `libyaml-cpp-dev` (originally `yaml-cpp-dev`) installed, for instance with apt-get:

```
$ apt-get install libyaml-cpp-dev
```

And `PyYaml` with `LibYaml` as well. But that's already the case based on your output.

I can't test it right now because I'm running OS X and `brew` has some trouble installing `yaml-cpp-dev` but if you follow [PyYaml documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), they are pretty clear that performance will be much better.

Comment: loading is still 12x slower with yaml.my sample is a list of 600,000 empty dictionaries. Yaml doesn't need to do anything extra except slightly cleverer syntax analysis which should take almost no extra time.

Comment: On mac: brew install yaml-cpp libyaml

Comment: Jivan you're a bloody legend.  I was going to rewrite some python code in C++ to speed things up.  My 6MB yaml file took 53 seconds to load using the standard yaml loader, and only 3 seconds with CLoader.

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying that the CLoader speedup is only of interest if you are running under Linux;  I just tried this under windows and it works, giving me a huge speedup.

Comment: The comment you link to is incorrect. PyYAML doesn't build a graph. There are no connections between the `Node`s that the representer emits, not even in the case of a single object occurring multiple times in a data-structure.

Comment: If you `cannot import name 'CLoader' from 'yaml'` try installing `libyaml-dev` and then reinstall pyyaml: `pip --no-cache-dir install --verbose --force-reinstall -I pyyaml` https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/108

Comment: But make sure you're using safe loaders - `from yaml import CSafeLoader as Loader, CSafeDumper as Dumper`

Answer (score 16):

For reference, I compared a couple of human-readable formats and indeed Python's yaml reader is *by far* the slowest. (Note the log-scaling in the below plot.) If you're looking for speed, you want one of the JSON loaders, e.g., [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/):

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import json
import tomllib

import numpy
import orjson
import pandas
import perfplot
import toml
import tomli
import ujson
import yaml
from yaml import CLoader, Loader


def setup(n):
    numpy.random.seed(0)
    data = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)

    with open("out.yml", "w") as f:
        yaml.dump(data.tolist(), f)

    with open("out.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data.tolist(), f, indent=4)

    with open("out.dat", "w") as f:
        numpy.savetxt(f, data)

    with open("out.toml", "w") as f:
        toml.dump({"data": data.tolist()}, f)


def yaml_python(arr):
    with open("out.yml", "r") as f:
        out = yaml.load(f, Loader=Loader)
    return out


def yaml_c(arr):
    with open("out.yml", "r") as f:
        out = yaml.load(f, Loader=CLoader)
    return out


# def zaml_load(arr):
#     with open("out.yml", "r") as f:
#         out = zaml.load(f)
#     return out["data"]


def json_load(arr):
    with open("out.json", "r") as f:
        out = json.load(f)
    return out


def ujson_load(arr):
    with open("out.json", "r") as f:
        out = ujson.load(f)
    return out


def orjson_load(arr):
    with open("out.json", "rb") as f:
        out = orjson.loads(f.read())
    return out


def loadtxt(arr):
    with open("out.dat", "r") as f:
        out = numpy.loadtxt(f)
    return out


def pandas_read(arr):
    out = pandas.read_csv("out.dat", header=None, sep=" ")
    return out.values


def toml_load(arr):
    with open("out.toml", "r") as f:
        out = toml.load(f)
    return out["data"]


def tomli_load(arr):
    with open("out.toml", "rb") as f:
        out = tomli.load(f)
    return out["data"]


def tomllib_load(arr):
    with open("out.toml", "r") as f:
        out = toml.load(f)
    return out["data"]


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        yaml_python,
        yaml_c,
        json_load,
        loadtxt,
        pandas_read,
        toml_load,
        tomli_load,
        tomllib_load,
        ujson_load,
        orjson_load,
    ],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(18)],
)

b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

Other answers here have said "use `CLoader`", which is a great tip, but if you're not using any custom classes (`!!foo` tags in your YAML) you can squeeze out another ~20% or so by using `CBaseLoader` instead of plain `CLoader`.

I had a script that went from ~2min37sec to ~2min7sec with this change.

Should be as easy as this:

```
import yaml

with open(...) as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.CBaseLoader)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not yet mentioned here there is also a [CSafeLoader](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) `C` class implementation available.

```
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as config_file:
    config_data = yaml.load(config_file, Loader=CSafeLoader)
```

I found it to be fractionally faster than `CLoader` (& both were around 15 times faster than the python implementation at least for small files under `50kb`)

As [noted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71137527/555451) `CBaseLoader` is around `20%` faster than the other `C` classes. This is due to:

> BaseLoader(stream) does not resolve or support any tags and construct
> only basic Python objects: lists, dictionaries and Unicode strings.

`CBaseLoader` does not recognise `boolean` in `yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `libyaml` I use this file with wrapped yaml logic:

```py
from typing import Dict

import yaml

try:
    from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
    LIBYAML_AVAILABLE = True
except ImportError:
    from yaml import Loader, Dumper
    LIBYAML_AVAILABLE = False


if LIBYAML_AVAILABLE:
    def yaml_load(stream) -> Dict:
        return yaml.load(stream, Loader=Loader)

    def yaml_dump(data, **kwargs) -> str:
        return yaml.dump(data, Dumper=Dumper, encoding='utf-8', allow_unicode=True, **kwargs).decode()
else:
    def yaml_load(stream) -> Dict:
        return yaml.safe_load(stream)

    def yaml_dump(data, **kwargs) -> str:
        return yaml.dump(data, encoding='utf-8', allow_unicode=True, **kwargs).decode()
```

Comment: Why does this need the if/else? You're importing the Loader and Dumper anyway...

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I also noticed that JSON is way faster. So a reasonable approach would be to convert YAML to JSON first. If you don't mind ruby, then you can get a big speedup and ditch the `yaml` install altogether:

```
import commands, json
def load_yaml_file(fn):
    ruby = "puts YAML.load_file('%s').to_json" % fn
    j = commands.getstatusoutput('ruby -ryaml -rjson -e "%s"' % ruby)
    return json.loads(j[1])
```

Here is a comparison for 100K records:

```
load_yaml_file: 0.95 s
yaml.load: 7.53 s
```

And for 1M records:

```
load_yaml_file: 11.55 s
yaml.load: 77.08 s
```

If you insist on using yaml.load anyway, remember to put it in a virtualenv to avoid conflicts with other software.

Comment: I don't mind ruby, but I do mind bogus answers. 1) you're not really using ruby, in your code you are using a [thin layer around libyaml C library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html): "The underlying implementation is the libyaml wrapper Psych". 2) you compare that with PyYAML without the libyaml C library. If you had, you would see that Python wrapping libyaml is not 7 times slower but only a few percent. 3) the announcement for the deprecation of the `commands` module was made in PEP 0361 in 2006, you still propose to use that more than **eleven** years later.

Comment: @Anthon If you have a better solution, by all means post it. I am fine if you like unnecessarily unstable libraries with multiple unnecessary dependencies and throwing away your software every 5 years. But then don't call *my* answer — which is based on packages that have been readily available for many years — "bogus".

Comment: `commands` is no longer readily available in maintained Python versions. I have no idea what the unstable libraries are, that you accuse me of liking.  I certainly don't like PyYAML, if that was what you are referrring to,  one of its main problems being that it is so stable, it doesn't support the latest YAML specification (1.2 released 2009).