What is the fastest way to read in a large yaml file containing lists of lists?
I have a number of yaml files I need to read in which contain lists of list. Here is a way to make some example data:
from time import time
import random
import yaml

# First make a list of lists
N = 2**17
lol = []
for _ in range(N):
    lol.append([random.uniform(0, 2) for _ in range(10)])

# Write the list of lists to a yaml file
with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(lol, outfile, default_flow_style=True)

I want to read them in as quickly as possible. Pyyaml is unfortunately slow.
# Now time how long it takes to read it back in
t = time()
with open("data.yml", "r") as f:
    lol = yaml.safe_load(f)
    print(f"Reading took {round(time()-t, 2)} seconds")

This give over 60 seconds for me.  The file is 27MB in size.
Is there a faster way to read in a yaml fie of exactly this format?

i am not sure, this is legitimate question.  Could you post an example of your YAML files?

@James I gave code to create an example data set. I could paste one of the lines from data.yml?

ah, thanks, i was reading too quickly

Don't use YAML for large blobs of data. Parsing YAML is complex and slow. If you need to store large blobs of data as text use JSON. If you're already stuck with YAML, then you could try using the CSafeLoader in pyyaml. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743711/can-i-speedup-yaml

@Dunes Sadly this is data created by other people that I have to read in.

Then use the CSafeLoader. You should get some speed up.

@Dunes Yes that does help. Is safe_load in python but CSafeLoader in C?

That is what the name implies, yes.

YAML is a superset of JSON, and coincidentally your data is also valid JSON (a list of lists of numbers).
Thus, using json.load() seems to be the simplest way:
from time import perf_counter
import json

t = perf_counter()

with open("data.yml", "r") as f:
    lol = json.load(f)
    print(perf_counter() - t)

$ python read.py
0.44149563400003444


wow, great solution to an interesting problem @InSync

You need to be careful with doing this. Whilst your example is valid JSON, your producer may be capable of emitting non-JSON data. eg. [.nan] or [.inf].

@Dunes random.uniform() will return neither NaN nor infinities. If that isn't the case, then the question is misleading and should be edited.

@InSync You are right. There will be  neither NaN nor infinities.
