# How could I validate a YAML structure in java programming

Tags: java, parsing, yaml, app.yaml, snakeyaml

I have a YAML file in my directory and I want to validate the YAML file was in correct structure using java programming. In online it having lot of YAML checker but I want to validate that on java programming.

Answer (score 5):

Just try to load it with your YAML parser/library. If that throws an error catch it and the structure is invalid. That is the way the online parsers work as well.

Comment: While this is correct, this approach doesn't cover all use cases that e.g. are covered by XSD for XML files. E.g. when a YAML file lacks a **mandatory** property, it is set to `null` in the created POJO/bean (without creating an error). 
What I said at least applies to snakeyaml. There might be more feature-rich parsers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use YAML parser/librairies like Jackson or SnakeYAML:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml

https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml

Answer (score 0):

There's also https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans

One issue I've found is that JSON objects are acceptable YAML 1.2 and, arguably, 1.1 formats.

[What valid JSON files are not valid YAML 1.1 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584985/what-valid-json-files-are-not-valid-yaml-1-1-files)