# JSON parse in ruby failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

In my rails database I have an object with a text field that is valid json:

```
"\"AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI\""
```

If I call JSON.parse on the field in ruby it errors with this:

```
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '"AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI"'
```

However, if I call JSON.parse on the same string in the browser it works.

Why is the ruby call failing?

Comment: Doesn't `JSON.parse` expect JSON, not a JSON fragment?

Comment: I think you're right. I assumed incorrectly they did similar things.

Comment: This works find on my end. You may want to update your `json` gem and try it out in `pry or irb`. I have tried out your string it passed correctly. I am using ruby 2.3.1

Comment: `JSON.parse(string)` and `JSON.load(string)`  both work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in the JSON parser that is fixed as of v2.0 of the [json gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/json).

```
# json_parser_test.rb
require 'json'
puts JSON.parse("\"AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI\"")
```

---

```
maxcal@MaxBook ~/p/s/tmp> gem list json

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.8.3)
json-schema (2.7.0)
jsonapi (0.1.1.beta6)
jsonapi-parser (0.1.1.beta3)
jsonapi-renderer (0.1.1.beta1)
multi_json (1.12.1, 1.11.2)
maxcal@MaxBook ~/p/s/tmp> ruby json_parser_test.rb 
/Users/maxcal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 784: unexpected token at '"AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI"' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /Users/maxcal/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    from json_parser_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Upgrading the JSON gem makes the parser error disappear:

```
maxcal@MaxBook ~/p/s/tmp> gem install json -v 2.0
Fetching: json-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-2.0.0
Building YARD (yri) index for json-2.0.0...
Done installing documentation for json after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
maxcal@MaxBook ~/p/s/tmp> ruby json_parser_test.rb 
AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI
```

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same issue with JSON.parse for a string nested in a JSON string. My solution was to escape `JSON::ParserError` with YAML.

```
YAML.load("\"AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI\"")
=> "AACAY, AAOI, AAON, AATI, ABAX,ZYXI"
```

Beware of gotchas though. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608600/is-it-safe-to-parse-json-with-yaml-load)

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() does not work with all string formats.
String needs to have following format.
"{\"AACAY\":\"AAOI\", \"AAON\":\"AATI\", \"ABAX\":\"ZYXI\"}"
which contains stringified object.