# MongoDB config file format

Tags: json, linux, mongodb, yaml

Can someone explain why MongoDB config file is written in YAML and not in JSON format?

This is not a problem for me, it's just consistency feeling that when everything is around JSON/BSON , then config file could also use that flow.

Is it more about some Linux conventions ?

Comment: Because YAML is a superset of JSON. As stated in [their docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#id1).

Comment: blueren: It's not a perfect superset, though, there are some rare exceptions

Comment: knm: one advantage of YAML is that it allows comments, which I consider very helpful in config files. Also, personally, I find it more readable and writeable if I don't have to put everything in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I did some quick research on this rather odd question. Found the below reasons:

1. Because YAML is a superset of JSON. As stated in [their docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#id1).
2. JSON can't have comments. Comments are something very important to a config file. Else you wouldn't know what is used to configure what!
3. [Discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729545/1745073)
4. [Discussion 2](https://arp242.net/weblog/json_as_configuration_files-_please_dont)
5. Brackets. Miss one bracket, and someone dies.

Comment: Normal questions are asked when one doesn't know something, odd questions are asked when curiosity doesn't know something. Thanks blueren, my curiosity owes you.