# AWS Cloudformation IoTAnalytics ServiceManagedS3 YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot, aws-iot-analytics

I have a AWS Cloudformation template (yaml-format) like this:

```
Datastore:
    Type: AWS::IoTAnalytics::Datastore
    Properties:
      DatastoreName: "DatastoreName"
      DatastoreStorage:
        ServiceManagedS3: ""
      RetentionPeriod:
        NumberOfDays: 7
```

I want to define a ServiceManagedS3-Bucket. Official documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iotanalytics-datastore-servicemanageds3.html) says it should just be an empty object. But when I do like above I get the following error: `Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DatastoreStorage/ServiceManagedS3} does not match type {Object}]`. If I change to an empty row like following Cloudformation complains about a null value.

```
      DatastoreStorage:
        ServiceManagedS3:
          
      RetentionPeriod:
        NumberOfDays: 7
```

Am I using the wrong .yaml-Syntax or what else am I doing wrong here? What is the correct way to declare an empty object?

Comment: Empty object would be: `ServiceManagedS3: {}`. Can you try this way?

Comment: Ah great, thanks! This works.

I researched for the reason: So yaml is a superset of JSON, so JSON-Code works here as an empty object. It can be so easy ;) Here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729545/6823586

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The empty `ServiceManagedS3` object is defined as follows:

```
ServiceManagedS3: {}
```

Therefore, the resource should be:

```
Datastore:
    Type: AWS::IoTAnalytics::Datastore
    Properties:
      DatastoreName: "DatastoreName"
      DatastoreStorage:
        ServiceManagedS3: {}
      RetentionPeriod:
        NumberOfDays: 7
```